# Redmine + Git = 404

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails, redmine

Пытаюсь прикрутить Git(2.6.4) к Redmine(3.3.2).

Мне передали папку с файлами (HEAD, description, config, index, COMMIT_EDITMSG, hooks, info, logs, objects, refs)

Я закинул ее на сервер в корень приложения. В Администрировании включил Git поддержку. В настройках проекта для хранилища указал путь "/repo/rep.git" . Появился раздел "Хранилище". Но перейдя туда получаю 404 и сообщение: Хранилище не содержит записи и/или исправления.

Подозревал, что путь указал не правильно, но вроде все норм... В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Эм? `Я закинул ее на сервер в корень приложения` -- в корне приложения создать папку .git а уже в неё закидывать файлы, не? Я не знаю, что такое redmine, но мне кажется что гит изкоробки работает с каталогом .git. Плюс, любопытно и наверное имеет значение -- возможно, redmine принимает только bare репозитории? (Либо наоборот, но вам дали bare репу)

Comment: @AK Мне передали сразу Bare (судя по набору файлов). Я в корне создал папку "repo", в нее положил папку "repo.git" с набором файлов. Я думаю не суть важно как папку обозвать, т.к. в настройках он просит путь

Comment: Тогда вероятно нужно ждать кого-то, кто сталкивался с подобными вопросами в Redmine. Я лишь могу посоветовать из общих соображений проверить владельца файлов и права доступа.